# Using git to edit remote branches

Tags: git

I am currently learning git and I am completely lost:

I want to do the following:

- I want to use git to fetch and edit (push to) remote branches.

How can I do this?

I was thinking of doing the following:

```
git branch -a
then 
git checkout remote/branch_name
git add .
git commit -m "..."
git push (which would push to the remote)
```

Is that how you do it>

Comment: I highly recommend that you learn the basics of how to use Git from the [FREE online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book). Recommended: chapters 1-3, 6-6.5.

Comment: I can understand that a git beginner is completely lost, because git a difficult learning experience. However this question does not match site policies http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist Have you done some research before asking the question? Every git tutorial explains this simple use case.

Answer (score -1):

If you change the history of repository, then remote push will be rejected. You'll have to force the push.

The git commands you're using

```
git branch -a
then 
git checkout remote/branch_name
git add .
git commit -m "..."
git push (which would push to the remote)
```

is fine to add new commit to the repository and it doesn't not change the history.

you can rewrite history with

```
git rebase -i <commit>
```

and then push to remote repo

```
git push --force origin <branch>
```

Comment: The user was learning git. git rebase is an advanced command and git push --force is a dangerous command. The answer is not suitable for a beginner and these commands are not needed in this case.

Comment: So, what do you recommend?